# How do I digitally sign a PDF in Java using a PEM file?

Tags: java, pdf, digital-signature, pem

I have exported my digital certificate to a password protected PFX file in windows.

How do I digitally sign a pdf with this?

Comment: Merely the certificate is not enough, you also need the private key. Or have you exported both?

Comment: The private key is included

Comment: Are there any additional boundary conditions? Open source? License restrictions? Commercial closed source usage?

Answer (score 3):

I am signing pdfs with the Aspose Pdf java sdk. These first two steps will likely be the same for any library.

If you don't already have a certificate generate an ssl private key with openssl. Obviously this will give warnings since it is not signed by a CA.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout testkey.pem -out testcert.pem -days 365
```

Next convert your key to a certificate in the pkcs12 format.

```
openssl pkcs12 -name test -export -in testcert.pem -inkey testkey.pem -out test.pfx
```

Lastly use the Aspose Pdf or some other library to sign the pdf

```
        PdfFileSignature pdfSignSingle = new PdfFileSignature();
        //Open the pdf
        pdfSignSingle.bindPdf(pdfFileInputStream);

        // Load the certificate using the com.aspose.pdf.PKCS1 object
        PKCS1 pkcs1 = new PKCS1(certificateFileInputStream, certificatePassword);
        pkcs1.setAuthority("Sample Person");
        pkcs1.setReason("I want to sign");
        pkcs1.setContactInfo("some contact info");
        pkcs1.setLocation("here");
        pkcs1.setShowProperties(false);

        // Apply the signature. (0,0) is in the lower left corner.
        pdfSignSingle.sign(1, true, new Rectangle(100, 100, 150, 50), pkcs1);
        // Apply the signature image
        pdfSignSingle.setSignatureAppearanceStream(imageFileInputStream);

        pdfSignSingle.save(pdfFileOutputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Our [SecureBlackbox](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/java-pdf.php) can be used to sign the PDF documents using certificates stored in files in various formats, in Windows CryptoAPI and on hardware devices via PKCS#11.

Answer (score -2):

[iTextPdf](http://itextpdf.com) is a good API for java, handling pdf files.
There is also a good documentation with examples: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures20130304.pdf

There is also an example for signing PDF documents